# is kernel panic an expected behavior in extreme memory pressure situation as shown in example?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, out-of-memory, android-memory

`kernel panic` is an action taken by an OS upon detecting an internal fatal error from which it cannot safely recover.

I tried an experiment in which I created the artificial memory pressure on device by forking and allocating a chunk of few MB and sleep infinitely. And I set the `oom_adj_score` of forked processes to `-1000` so that LMK couldn't kill them.

Sharing the output of `ps | grep artificial_mem_pressure`. Looking at `RSS` field you can see that each `process` is consuming a lot of RAM.

**NOTE:** I have just snippet a few process not all.

```
[ 5086]     0  5086    67990    12001      36     2881         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5092]     0  5092    67990    11897      35     2853         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5098]     0  5098    67990    11590      35     2969         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5104]     0  5104    67990    11446      35     2983         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5110]     0  5110    67990    11276      34     2954         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5116]     0  5116    67990    11175      33     2924         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5122]     0  5122    67990    11002      35     2900         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5129]     0  5129    67990    10889      33     2879         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5137]     0  5137    67990    10646      33     2927         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5143]     0  5143    67990    10507      32     2932         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5149]     0  5149    67990    10293      32     2949         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5155]     0  5155    67990    10231      32     2879         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5202]     0  5202    67990    10196      32     2778         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5216]     0  5216    67990     9960      31     2818         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5329]     0  5329    67990     9891      31     2752         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5337]     0  5337    67990     9917      30     2590         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5343]     0  5343    67990     9794      31     2515         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5350]     0  5350    67990     9764      29     2413         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5356]     0  5356    67990     9550      29     2428         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5362]     0  5362    67990     9335      30     2512         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5368]     0  5368    67990     9193      29     2465         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5374]     0  5374    67990     9039      28     2487         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5380]     0  5380    67990     8787      28     2540         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5386]     0  5386    67990     8735      28     2465         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5392]     0  5392    67990     8602      28     2385         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5398]     0  5398    67990     8662      27     2207         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5404]     0  5404    67990     8476      26     2181         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5410]     0  5410    67990     8425      26     2104         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5416]     0  5416    67990     8396      26     1995         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5422]     0  5422    67990     8483      26     1724         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5428]     0  5428    67990     8350      25     1709         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
[ 5434]     0  5434    67990     8374      26     1531         -1000 artificial_mem_pressure
```

I know creating such a huge pressure on device will result in shortage of memory. As a result `Memory reclamation algorithm` will try to kill some process which are killable. Now in my case as I have all the processes whose `oom_score_adj=-1000` hence LMK can't kill such process.

As a result I am seeing this message:

`Kernel panic - not syncing: Out of memory and no killable processes...`

**My question:** 
is it expected behavior in such case ? If yes, please explain.

Comment: @AlexHoppus is kernel panic an expected behavior in such case where No memory is reclaimable ? If Yes, then why ? means can't reclaim algorithm go beyond to kill the user-space process whose score we explicitly set to -1000.

Comment: Yes, because "no killable processes" as kernel said

Comment: Ok Thanks. But, can't reclaim algorithm go beyond to kill the user-space process whose score we explicitly set to -1000.

Comment: As i see from your log - it can't. Do you want to change the kernel in order to kill such processes or what is the point? Why you can't just not set oom_score_adj=-1000?

Comment: Setting the oom_score_adj to -1000 was intentional. Do you want to change the kernel in order to kill such processes. Yes if possible. 
I am asking why android didn't take care of such cases.  If such process can create this situation, then memory management should be intelligent enough to tackle such cases ?

Answer (score 1):

From man:

```
lowest possible value, -1000, is equivalent to disabling OOM-killing
```

Why kernel should kill processes if you intentionally said "don't kill them"? In this case kernel have no other choice - it panics. Even if it means death of all processes kernel honestly performs your orders.
If you need to avoid this - just change `oom_score_adj`